# Problems getting USBasp to connect with ATMEGA16 / ATMEGA32 Development board and PC in order to flash a bios chip

Tags: attiny, usbasp

AVR ATMEGA16 Minimum System Board ATmega32 Development Board + USB ISP USBasp Programmer ISP ATTiny 51 Board and PLCC32 to DIP32 EZ Programmer Adapter Socket

Hi all,

Very very new to all this...

I bought the above with the intentions on flashing a bios file to a PL-CC 32 socket chip. I have spent a good amount of time getting nowhere unfortunately. With all the guides I found and advice I have seen on other peoples forum posts I havent progresed very far.

So far I have only managed to flash the latest firmware to the USBasp - after that I can't get any programs to show/connect/recognise that they are successfully connected to the USBasp.

I am obviously missing something or doing something wrong but I just can't work out what it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Been at this a while and tried a lot of things so I have probably missed somethings I have tried.

I am just looking for information/advice on what to do and how to connect etc... after flashing firmware to the USBasp.

I am using Windows 10 64
I closed off JP1 in order to flash the new firmware on the USBasp
I have flashed the latest firmware to the USBasp via another USBasp
I have tried using elevated CMD with avrdude installed on my system
eXtreme Burner - AVR
AVRDUDESS
Arduino IDE

I get errors such as detecting the MCU...
Warning: Unable to detect MCU

and

avrdude -c usbasp -p m8 -P usb

avrdude.exe: error: usbasp_transmit: No error
avrdude.exe: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 0
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
this check.

avrdude.exe: error: usbasp_transmit: No error

[image: Programmer]

[image: Programmer]

[image: Adapter for Socket PL-CC 32]

Comment: It is unclear from your explanation exactly where the problem is. There is no mention of what AVR chip you are trying to program nor how you propose to program the bios chip. All this is horribly ancient and was supplanted by the Arduino years ago.

Comment: I was just looking for cheap way to flash a bios chip, but looks like I have gone the wrong way about it. 

My main issue is I cannot get anything to communicate/connect with the board I have connected to the USBasp, even the USBasp was said to not be connected. If it is the case that I need to go the Arduino way then thats what I will have to do, but the info I orginally found lead me to buy the above and give that a go, but unfortunately it hasn't worked. Sometimes I get confused by the information I am finding. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You probably want something like a tl866 universal chip programmer.

Comment: Cheers Kartman I will have a look at one of those.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

First of all, USBasp is a program to flash programs into AVR microcontrollers, not a program to flash arbitrary flash chips. It needs USBasp compatible progammer which connects the target AVR to your PC via USB.

Secondly, the USBasp adapter you have with the DIP ZIF socket is meant to allow the USBasp board to program AVRs in DIP packages.

So connecting an arbitrary flash chip through a PLCC to DIP adapter to connect it to a DIP socket intended to take AVRs for programming won't really achieve anything useful. The USBasp program says just that - it can't find an AVR to program, as there is a random flash chip on behalf of the AVR.

On the contrary, you don't know if the pinouts are even remotely compatible, so it is possible that incorrect supply voltages applied to incorrect pins on the flash chip may have damaged it.

So in short, if you want to program flash chips, you would buy a programmer intended to program flash chips, not a programmer intended to program AVR microcontrollers.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, I guess some more research on my part is needed. I thought I saw a video using this equipment but I guess I have got muddled on the way. I shall have another look in to it and see what I come up with. Thanks again.